# How can I use a bash script to run postgres when launching AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, geoserver

I'm testing some set ups for EC2 to run geoserver. When launching the EC2 instance I have a bash script to speed things up. However, when it gets to the point of creating a postgres db it fails. Below is an excerpt of the script and it appears to fail after the second line:

```
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo su postgres
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data &
exit

yum install gcc make gcc-c++ libtool libxml2-devel -y
# ..... etc etc
```

I've SSHed into an instance an run the above code manually, then made an AMI from that instance which works. I'd still like to know how to have a bash script for Amazon linux that can also start postgres.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: There's no error reporting I can find when launching an instance using a bash script (please let me know where to look). I can tell roughly where it is failing as the script stops. SSHing in reveals gcc etc are not installed and none of the directories are made after the `sudo su postgres` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put `sudo su postgres` in a script to have the subsequent lines be executed by the postgres user.  You need to write like:

```
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data

sudo -u postgres initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo -u postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data &

yum install ...
```

Comment: The first `sudo -u postgres` works but the line `sudo -u postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data &` seems to make it hang and adding the `exit` closes out of the shell.

Comment: Dropped the `exit` and realised there was another `exit` later in the script. Just tested and it is all working.